# Attack Targetted Enemy Only

Tags: unity, c#

I have a perfectly working targetting script and I want to be able to deal damage to my currently selected enemy. I have a targetting script which is below:?

```
public GameObject enemy;
public List<Transform> targets;
public Transform selectedTarget;
public string targetTag = "Enemy";
private Transform myTransform;
private enemyHealth eHealth;

//Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    targets = new List<Transform>();
    selectedTarget = null;
    myTransform = transform;        
    AddAllEnemies();
    eHealth = GetComponent<enemyHealth>();
}

public void AddAllEnemies() {
    GameObject[] go = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(targetTag);     
    foreach(GameObject enemy in go) {
        AddTarget(enemy.transform);
    }
}

public void AddTarget(Transform enemy) {
    targets.Add(enemy);
}

private void SortTargetsByDistance() {
    targets.RemoveAll(target => target == null);
    targets.Sort(delegate(Transform t1, Transform t2) { 
        return (Vector3.Distance(t1.position,    myTransform.position).CompareTo)
            (Vector3.Distance(t2.position, myTransform.position));
    });
}

private void TargetEnemy() {
    if(selectedTarget == null) {
        SortTargetsByDistance();
        selectedTarget = targets[0];
    } else {
        int index = targets.IndexOf(selectedTarget);    
        if (index < targets.Count -1) {
            index++;
        } else {
            index = 0;    
        }

        DeselectTarget();
        selectedTarget = targets[index];
    }
    SelectTarget ();
}

private void SelectTarget() {
    selectedTarget.GetComponent<Renderer> ().material.color = Color.red;

    enemyHealth eh = (enemyHealth)GetComponent("EnemyHealth");
    eh.target = enemy;
}

private void DeselectTarget() {
    selectedTarget.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.blue;
    selectedTarget = null;
}

//Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Tab)) {
        TargetEnemy ();
    }
}
```

and I have my enemyHealth script which is where I am handling the health and also dealing damage.

```
public float eHealth = 100;
public Slider EnemyHealth;
public GameObject target;

private float MHCD; // MeleeHit CD

void Start () {
    EnemyHealth = GetComponent<Slider> ();
}

public void MeleeHit() {

    float distance = Vector3.Distance (target.transform.position, transform.position);

    Vector3 dir = (target.transform.position - transform.position).normalized;

    float direction = Vector3.Dot (dir, transform.forward);

    if (distance < 4) {
        if (distance > 0) {
            eHealth -= Random.Range (4, 9);
            EnemyHealth.value = eHealth;
        }
    } else {
        Debug.LogWarning ("You are too far away!");
    }
    Debug.Log (eHealth);
}

void Update() {

    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Alpha1) && Time.time - MHCD > 1) { 
        MeleeHit ();
        MHCD = Time.time;
    }
```

does anyone know how I can link the two so I am only dealing damage to my selectedTarget?

What the code is currently doing is attacking all enemies instead of just 1. I need it to only attack the selectedTarget until I switch to the others.

Comment: Please check where *exactly* those error messages occur. You can see that by double-clicking on them in the Unity console. `NullReferenceException` is one of the most common errors when programming C# and the result of many different newbie mistakes. `MeleeHit` isn't called anywhere in the code you posted, yet you have an error message about it, so you aren't posting at least one important script file.

Comment: I've edited my question, there is now 1 error. I edited above I can attack my enemy just fine but it attacks all of my enemies instead of just 1. Also my targetting won't include (clones) in its loop

Comment: `eh` appears to be a float-variable. So `eh.target` should not work. But that should be a compiler error.

Comment: got rid of the  eh = 100; and float variable up top but I still get the same errors

Answer (score 0):

In the following snippet `eh` is being set to a null value.

```
private void SelectTarget() {
    selectedTarget.GetComponent<Renderer> ().material.color = Color.red;

    enemyHealth eh = (enemyHealth)GetComponent("EnemyHealth");
    eh.target = enemy;
}
```

This is due to typo in the name of the class. Try using this instead:

```
enemyHealth eh = (enemyHealth)GetComponent("enemyHealth");
```

---

To avoid this kind of error in the future I suggest:

1. Using a consistent naming scheme e.g. all types use [CamelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase).
2. Use the [generic](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GenericFunctions.html) form of `GetComponent()` as it allows compile time type checking:

   ```
   enemyHealth eh = GetComponent<enemyHealth>();
   ```

Comment: That has fixed the error (I had to take out those 2 lines of code completely) but still leaves with me the problem of only attacking 1 enemy instead of all of them.